# How to restart Orbit Controls after target is set

Tags: javascript, three.js, user-controls

I set a new target for my `THREE.OrbitControls` on a mouse click event and it works great. But after the camera pans to the new location, I lose all interaction with the mouse.
I am updating this question with the working code.

I think I broke the controls when I set the camera z and target z to the same value.

The broken code is here:
http://www.kreativperspektiv.com/pb2/chartlock.html

The working code is here:
http://www.kreativperspektiv.com/pb2/chartcorrect.html

panCam(500,200,4000,1000);

```
        var xTarget=0;
        var yTarget=0;
        var zTarget=0;
        var tweenDuration=0;

        function panCam(xTarget,yTarget,zTarget,tweenDuration){

          TWEEN.removeAll();

          var camNewPosition= { x : xTarget, y : yTarget, z : zTarget};
          var targetNewPos = {x : xTarget, y : yTarget, z : 0};

          var camTween = new TWEEN.Tween(camera.position).to(camNewPosition, tweenDuration).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut).start();
          var targetTween = new TWEEN.Tween(controls.target).to(targetNewPos, tweenDuration).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut).start();
    }
```

Comment: Code please? You should always include all relevant code in your question. Read also more about this in [the StackOverflow guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So you need to show in your code how you *"set the target"*?

Comment: Updated with code.  My apologies.  I was just looking for a general guideline on how the reset works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot update target like this:

> controls.target = newTarget;

That will break your controls.
Instead have to set target using the setter method or copy method:

```
controls.target.copy( newTarget );
controls.target.set( x, y, z ) // where x, y and z are the new values
```

---

### UDPATE

If you want to use TWEEN, just try like this:

```
new TWEEN.Tween(camera.position).to(newPosition, tweenDuration);
new TWEEN.Tween(controls.target).to(newTarget, tweenDuration);
```

Comment: Got it.  I updated the function at it seems to be responding correctly.  It does a little jump on clicking but I think I can fix that.  Will update with working code.

Comment: That works to not break the controls but I think there is an issue with my tween as the orbit jumps before the camera moves.  See updated code and link.

Comment: Should I ask another question or just keep updating this one?

Comment: @Migpics That would actually be considered another question, but I added an update to my answer. Try like that, if it doesn't work I suggest you ask a new question...

Comment: Hi @Wilt.  I found out what was breaking the controls.  I had set the controls target z value to the camera position z value.  See the links above on the updated question.